# Bash - удаление блоков текста

Tags: bash

Основная задача: файл имеет блоки текста, начинающиеся с текущей даты (`date +"%d/%m/%y"`) и заканчивающиеся пустой строкой или строками. Мой конечный скрипт должен стирать этот блок при совпадении с текущей датой. Я планировал идти циклом. При совпадении с датой - ставить флажок (остановка вывода в файл). При пустой строке и поставленом флажке - убирать флажок.
Пока что, я просто пытался отслеживать пустые строки, но не выходит.

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `cat ./test2`; do
if [[ "$line" != "" ]]
then echo $line
else echo
fi
done
```

Файл вида:

```
abc1

abc2

abc3
```

Вот как раз эти пустые строки и теряются в цикле.

Comment: переводы строк уже отслеживается: вы получаете по строке на каждой итерации написанного вами цикла. и выводите вы уже «с переводами строк». суть обоих вопросов непонятна. и эти вопросы не соответствуют заголовку (в котором речь уже про пустые строки).

Comment: Файл вида: <br/> abc1 <br/><br/> abc2 <br/> <br/>abc3 <br/> <br/> Вот как раз эти пустые строки и теряются в цикле. Так...не работает форматирование.

Comment: Делается *sed*ом в одну строку, не изобретайте костыли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вот как раз эти пустые строки и теряются в цикле

потому что вы конструкцией

```
for line in `cat ./test2`
```

читаете **не** строки, а весь файл как одну строку, разбивая её на т.н. «токены», то есть группы символов, между которыми вставлены разделители (по умолчанию — «пробельные символы» — пробелы, знаки табуляции, переводы строк), по одному токену на каждой итерации цикла.

если нужно читать по строке на каждой итерации цикла, то делайте это «более естественным» для оболочки путём:

```
cat file | while read line; do
  ...
done
```

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Непонятна задача. Ты явно не это хотел. Но здесь не место для дискуссий, не место для личных мнений, тут один вопрос - один ответ

> 1) Вывести его со всеми переводами

`cat file.txt`

Если надо без переводов-разделителей, то:

`cat file.txt | grep -v ^$`

> Понять, как в баше отслеживать перевод строки

`cat file.txt | sed "s.^$.АААААААААА ТУТ БЫЛА ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА.g"`

Comment: *Если надо без переводов, то* — и дальше предлагаете выводить как раз **вместе с** переводами строк.

Comment: `cat file.txt | sed "s.^$.АААААААААА ТУТ БЫЛА ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА.g"` — и какое отношение эта **пустая строка** имеет к **переводам строк** (которые есть после **каждой** строки)?

Comment: Уточнил. Ориентировался на автора и его вопрос. Про удаление \н тут явно не спрашивали

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Основная задача: файл имеет блоки текста, начинающиеся с даты и заканчивающиеся пустой строкой или строками. Мой конечный скрипт должен стирать этот блок при совпадении с текущей датой. Я планировал идти циклом. При совпадении с датой - ставить флажок. При пустой строке и поставленом флажке - убирать его.

Comment: по-моему, стало ещё хуже. что такое «переводы-разделители»? мне кажется, вы поторопились с ответом на вопрос (точнее, несколько вопросов), суть которых в данный момент не ясна.

Comment: @keltkelt, внесите корректировки прямо в текст вопроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: @keltkelt, во-первых, тут не делают чужую работу, а отвечают на конкретные вопросы. Во-вторых, суть вопроса от этого понятнее не становится. В-третьих, рекомендую почитать man grep

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я ответил в меру своего понимания. Двойные переводы строк (так корректней, но автор их назвал просто переводами), они же пустые строки, достаточно часто встречаются в разных файлах и могут быть объектом для парсинга. Если мой ответ тебе не нравится, то нажми минусик.

Answer (score 2):

Если блок начинается на дату: `/^\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}$/`, а заканчивается на пустую строку `/^\s*$/`, то можно [flip-flop оператор](https://habrahabr.ru/post/87272/) использовать, чтобы удалить такие блоки:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /^\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d$/../^\s*$/' tests2
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/KFpeer).

Чтобы удалить блоки только с текущей датой в формате `%Y.%m.%d`:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -ne 'BEGIN{$today=localtime->ymd(".")};
    print unless ($_ == $date) .. /^\s*$/' test2
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/SSix5R).

Похожее можно с помощью `awk` сделать:

```
awk -v today=$(date +'%Y.%m.%d') '$0 == today,!NF {next} {print}' test2
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/6XFfXW).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Мне нужно вырезать с текущей датой, в баше, как выяснил, это date=`eval date +"%d/%m/%y"`. А перл совсем еще не знаю...

Comment: @keltkelt: обновил ответ, чтобы блоки только с текущей датой удалялись

Comment: Благодарю! Да уж, с перлом придется разбираться...

Comment: @keltkelt не обязательно perl, можно к примеру, awk использовать.